# Grouping results in KO.js foreach binding

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I can't figure out how to work with iterations in foreach of KOjs. 
What I need is to group contents of an array like this

```
Var x = [{name: Joel, sex: male}, {name: Eric, sex: male},{name:Elliot, sex:female}, {name:Mary, sex:female}]
```

So the resulting data-bind foreach would display the sex of the person, but only once as a label. 
Something like this

```
-male
Joel
Eric
-female
Elliot
Mary
```

With normal for loops it is as simple as making a variable that holds last entry's gender, and prints the new one if it changes. Something like

```
If(this.sex != cachedSex){
 cachedSex=this.sex;
console.log(cachedSex);
}
```

But I can't figure it out how to make this in KO.js
Please give me an advice.

Comment: Please update us on your efforts

Answer (score 1):

Knockout lets you use computed observables which solve this problem in a clever way :)

If you want a full code example [**here is a fiddle illustrating this solution**](http://jsfiddle.net/hDdb9/).

Lets say all your people are called `people` and it's an `observableArray` :

```
var that = this;
this.people = ko.observableArray([{name: Joel, sex: male}, {name: Eric, sex: male},{name:Elliot, sex:female}, {name:Mary, sex:female}])
```

Now we only want the males and females apart:

```
this.males = ko.computed(function(){
    return that.people().filter(function(person){
        return person.sex === "male";
    });
});
this.females = ko.computed(function(){
    return that.people().filter(function(person){
        return person.sex === "females ";
    });
});
```

(Of course - if you repeat this sort of code a lot - make a function out of it instead of repeating yourself :) )

Then you can do the `foreach` binding normally, once for `females` and once for `males`

Comment: Thank you for the idea. But is there any less hardcode-dependant way to solve it? For example, if I need to use not only gender filtering, but group filtering, and I dont know how many groups there are going to be?

Comment: @Kresent The core concept is to use computed observables here :) You can create a `computed` that groups them by a given property name using `reduce` or even a normal for loop (gender, etc), and then use a nested foreach binding: foreach group - group title, foreach member - show member data.

Answer (score 0):

Benjamins answer is correct but there is another way without having to create additional observableArrays.  In the view you can simply do a foreach binding and put a sliver of logic there to handle filtering.  Its the simplest way but down the road you could argue there may be alternatives such as benjamins which are more suited, depending on your application

### Men

This would allow you to do some basic filtering in the view.  You could also set up a custom binding handler that you could pass in the filter to make it even more efficient and clean